# Override Variable in Array - Smarty

Tags: arrays, smarty, cs-cart

A slightly strange one, but I'm using an ecommerce platform called CS-Cart which uses smarty for it's templating language. It has a smarty debug console which allows me to see which variables the current page is using.

For example, here is an array that is being used (I have shortened this for the example):

```
 Appearance => Array (33)
  products_per_page => "10"
  admin_products_per_page => "10"
  admin_elements_per_page => "10"
  columns_in_products_list => "3"
  default_products_sorting => "price"
```

I would like to be able to assign a different value to `default_products_sorting => "price"`
I plan to do this in the header of my document as it will be included in an IF statement whereby the variable is only changed if certain conditions are true.

Is this even possible in smarty? (without the use of PHP) and if so any ideas on how this could be achieved? I've scoured Google but so far turned up a blank.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the variable like this

```
{$Appearance.default_products_sorting = "NEW_VALUE"}
```

And after this line, if you use `{$Appearance.default_products_sorting}` you should get the new value.

I just checked and it worked.

You should change it at the top of your smarty template, so that any code that is using this variable get the updated value.

Looks like the above method doesn't work for `arrays`. You can consider using the custom function from this link http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7201&highlight=create+array

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've just tried this and it didn't work but then I noticed it's inside {$settings} - what i'm unsure of now is how the syntax should change? EDIT: I've tried {$settings.Appearance.default_products_sorting = "NEW_VALUE"} but this just seems to print the old value.

Comment: in that case you can try `$settings.Appearance.default_products_sorting`

Comment: It wont work in case of array though works for simple variables, try this instead
http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7201&highlight=create+array

Comment: thanks, I've tried that but it doesn't seem to play nicely with CS-Cart, looks like this needs a re-think. Thanks for your answer. Please put that link in your main answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Added. One thing, cant you just find where that `val` is being used to sort values and change that code instead in a way so it doesn't mess up other code.

Comment: I'm also looking for this but it's such a huge system that trying to find exactly where things are is a minefield!

Answer (score 0):

`{php}$this->_tpl_vars['Appearance']['default_products_sorting'] = "value";{/php}`

I haven't tested this outside WHMCS but from a quick search it looks like it would still apply.

Found here: http://forum.whmcs.com/showthread.php?28490-Modify-single-item-of-smarty-array