# Smatry replace not print array of variable

Tags: replace, smarty, smarty3

```
{$variable.fieldname} = Username
```

My input `<input type="text">`

I have Tried `{$variable|replace:"type=\"text\"":'type="text" placeholder="{$variable.fieldname}"'}`

Getting Output: `<input type="text" placeholder="{$variable.fieldname}">`

Expected: `<input type="text" placeholder="Username">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override Variable in Array - Smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848360/override-variable-in-array-smarty)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `assign` an additional variable and use `regex_replace` method instead.

```
{assign var="newvar" value="type=\"text\" placeholder=\"{$variable.fieldname}\""}

{$variable|regex_replace:"/type=\"text\"/":{$newvar}}
```